# Как передать значение переменной из одного окна в другое | kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы после ввода каких-то данных в TextInput одного окна, я мог бы вывести введенные данные в Label другого окна

[Python код](https://codeshare.io/5DMb8l)

[Код kv файла](https://codeshare.io/aJDAmZ)

На данный момент, при попытке запуска программы интерпретатор выдает ошибку в файле .kv на строке 46 из-за того что не получается найти переменную указаную в другом окне.

*Если кто-то даст хотя-бы подсказку или ссылки на какие-то метиралы, которые могут помочь, буду очень благодарен*

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но методом тыка нашел метод `get_screen()` для `ScreenManager`. Чтобы его использовать надо объявить SM глобально, как то вот так:

```
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [ConfigWindow(name="config"), MainWindow(name="main")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)
# указываем какая форма будет показываться первой
sm.current = 'main'
```

Ну а дальше, например, мы хотим кнопке `cfg_btn` на форме `config` изменить текст:

```
 sm.get_screen('config').cfg_btn.text = self.desc.text
```

Этот кусок пихаем в тело функции, а саму функцию вешаем на `on_release;` кнопки.